# Pass a variable by href?

Tags: php, html, kendo-grid, phpixie

I've read a few resources and figured out the gist of doing this, but I'm having a hard time with it.

I want to pass a var to `'<a href="documents/edit">'` so I tried 

`'<a href="documents/edit?var=<?php echo $this->request->post("doc_id")?>">'`, 
but it breaks my site. I don't really know what I'm doing so could someone let me know if I did something wrong?

This is all taking place within an html file, fyi.

Edit: Another thing about this is that I'm using Kendo and PHPixie.

Comment: What is edit? a php file?

Comment: @kimbarcelona Yes, sort of. Documents is the php file and edit is a method within.

Comment: Is there a PHP error? If post is not a method in the object, then you will get a error.

Comment: I believe that's not the right way to call the method inside documents.php using href

Comment: Yes, what's the error if there is

Comment: @kimbarcelona Parts of my webpage aren't rendering. It's all jumbled up.

Comment: I don't think you're using that class right. `$this` is usually called when you're declaring variables for the class to use.

Comment: i have no idea about the frameworkm but if you are trying to echo the post parameter there, `echo $_POST['doc_id'] ` might work as well

Comment: What extension is the file having ? `.html` or `.php` ? For PHP code to get interpreted , that file should have a `.php` extension or should be included in a script having `.php` extension .

Comment: Nested double quotes??

Comment: Thanks for all of the replies, but I've found another file that does something similar to what I want. It's something like this: `<?php echo $exepath; ?>users/addedit?user_id=<?php echo $doc->doc_id ?>`. I'm gonna try that and hopefully it'll work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching the code I have, I found that this is the correct way to do things:

```
<a href="<?php echo $exepath; ?>documents/edit?doc_id=document_id"></a>
```

Hopefully, this will help out anyone using PHPixie or Kendo in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Well, actually in PHPixie you cannot use `$this->request` in your views because $this doesn't represent the Controller (in which you can find the variable $request) but the View !

The best way to pass the $_POST to your view is by doing this :

```
public function action_myFunction()
{
    $this->view->post = $this->request->post();
    $this->view->subview = 'myView';
}
```

And in your view, you can do

```
<div>
    <?=$post['doc_id'];?>
</div>
```

You can find more info on this blog : http://phpixie.jeromepasquier.com/accessing-variables-view/

By the way, it is good practice to always **prepend** your `href` and `src` with a starting slash. Why ? Because if you are on `http://example.com/exa/mple` and you want to go to `http://example.com/doc_id` you will need to tell the browser that you start the url from the host. Otherwise without a starting slash, you will end up on `http://example.com/exa/doc_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Views **should not** access POST directly. Ever.

Passing the POST to your view will work for sure, but violates the main concept of the MVC.

Doing this:

```
<?=$post['doc_id'];?>
```

Will throw an error if the POST var "doc_id" is not present in the $post array because there is no error checking and PHPixie works in strict mode.

The BEST way to assign a variable that will be used later on the view like this:

```
public function action_myFunction()
{
    $this->view->doc_id = $this->request->post('doc_id');  //will return NULL if not present, checking logic should be done before if needed
    $this->view->subview = 'myView';
}
```

And in your view:

```
<div>
    <?= $doc_id ?>
</div>
```